# Marker in google map android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am displaying marker with the help of loops by taking the values from json array.The latitude and longitude are getting updated continously.Beacuse of which the markers are blinking..How can i stop markers to blink.

```
for(int i=0;i<TOTAL_LIST.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject c = TOTAL_LIST.getJSONObject(i);
    String nam=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    Str_NAM=nam;

    String mob=c.getString(TAG_MOB);
    Str_MOB=mob;

    String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
    la= Double.parseDouble(lat);
    String lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);
    ln= Double.parseDouble(lng);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            options.position(new LatLng(la,ln));
            options.title(Str_NAM);
            googleMap.addMarker(options);                                      
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Comment: i am taking the values of latitude and longitude from database and using that values i am displaying marker on map.whenever a new value is being fetched the marker position is updated and marker is blinked so how can i stop marker from blinking.